# Synchronize two azure storage accounts (close to real time as possible) in different subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I am looking for an automated solution that essentially syncs two storage accounts across different subscriptions as close to real time as possible, all contained within cloud.

`Azcopy sync` appears to be ideal for my needs seeing as it only transfers changed files to save on ingress/egress traffic costs but unsure if this can be implemented within azure automation - which seems to be the only way to execute code on a scheduler within azure ?

Overall i just need Storage account in subscription A synced -> Storage Account in Subscription B

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this use Azure Event Grid, which basically stores events whenever something happen in your storage account. Then, you can trigger some other process (Azure Functions, Logic Apps) to perform the same operation in the other subscription. I believe this is the closest to real-time you'll find.